# how to write automatic Twitter login script

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using urllib and BeautifulSoup to crawl twitter data. But when I try to crawl someone else's data, for example, https://twitter.com/twitterapi/followers, it needs login.

How can I implement automatically login with Python script? Or, how to simulate the login process using Python?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to screen-scrape. Twitter has a perfectly functional API.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Comment: The reason I'm trying to avoid using Twitter API is that I don't want to be restricted by the 'rate limit'. Instead, I want to parse the page directly.

Comment: You're likely to get blocked entirely if you scrape excessively.